# ¿Cómo cambiar datos de un Array usando métodos? JAVA

Tags: java, array, netbeans

Tengo una clase Cuentas con los siguientes datos encapsulados:

```
public class Cuentas {
private int nC;
private String usuario;
private String contra;
private String nombre;
private int monto;
private int tipo; [...]}
```

Y en la clase CajeroAutomaticoBeta (main) tengo estas declaraciones globales:

```
ublic static int cnt=0;   //contador de cuentas
static int op;
public static Cuentas[] cuentas = new Cuentas[100]; //Array para almacenar cuentas
```

Uso un método crearCuentas(); para solicitar los datos a ingresar en la cuenta:

```
public static void crearCuenta(){
    t=new Scanner(System.in);
    int nC = cnt;
    System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("   --------- CREACION DE CUENTAS ---------");
    System.out.println("NOTA: el usuario debe establecerse con numeros, ej:[1111]\n");
    System.out.print("Ingrese el nuevo usuario: ");
    String usuario = t.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Ingrese la contraseña: ");
    String contra = t.nextLine();
    System.out.print("¿Quien es el titular de la nueva cuenta?: ");
    String nombre = t.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Ingrese el monto de apertura de la cuenta: ");
    int monto = t.nextInt();
    if(monto == 0){
        System.out.println("--Usted no puede abrir la cuenta con 0 quetzales.--");
        System.out.println("Ingrese el monto de apertura de la cuenta: ");
        monto = t.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print("Seleccione el tipo de cuenta: ");
    System.out.println("\n1.-Ahorro\n2.-Monetaria\n3.-Ahorro programado");
    System.out.print("->");
    int tipo = t.nextInt();
    cuentas[cnt] = nuevaCuenta(nC, usuario, contra, nombre, monto, tipo); 
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Presione cualquier numero para continuar: ");
    int opn = s.nextInt();
    if(opn>=0){
        menuCuentas();
    }
    cnt++;
}
```

Y otro método nuevaCuenta(); para enviar los datos que recibí desde crearCuentas(); y enviarlos a los setters de Cuentas:

```
public static Cuentas nuevaCuenta(int nC, String usuario, String contra, String nombre, int monto, int tipo){
    Cuentas cuenta = new Cuentas();
    cuenta.setnC(nC);
    cuenta.setUsuario(usuario);
    cuenta.setContra(contra);
    cuenta.setNombre(nombre);
    cuenta.setMonto(monto);
    return cuenta;
}
```

Ahora bien. Necesito hacer un retiro de monto usando otro método llamado Retirar();

```
    public static void Retirar(){
    Scanner v=new Scanner(System.in);
    int opR, ret;
    System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("   --------- RETIROS MONETARIOS ---------");
    System.out.println("[1]-Q.50\n[2]-Q.100\n[3]-Q.200\n[4]-Q.300\n[5]-Q.500\n[6]-Q.800\n[7]-Q.1000\n");
    System.out.print("Seleccione el monto que desea retirar:");
    opR=s.nextInt();
    switch(opR){
        case 1:
            //operacion o metodo de retiro
            break;}
```

Pero me gustaría saber cómo puedo modificar los datos de monto en la cuenta seleccionada. Supongamos que el usuario desea retirar Q.50, ¿cómo puedo **restar** ese valor de retiro al monto inicial estabecido en *monto* y poder guardarlo?

Comment: Te estás liando demasiado en el código metiendo en las clases y en sus métodos cosas que pertenecen al contexto y dejando de meter lo que tendrías que meter. Es un grave error de diseño meter un `Scanner` en el método `retirar`. Lo que tiene que haber en ese método es un control del balance, restando el valor que se manda a retirar. Tienes q recuperar el dato fuera de la clase y del método y luego invocar la instancia de la clase que tengas en el contexto para retirar. Algo así, **fuera de la clase**: `mCuentas=new Cuentas();  /*Recuperar el valor con el Scanner /* mCuentas.retirar(elValor);`

Comment: Me mencionas que es fuera de la clase, digamos ¿tengo que ponerlo fuera de mi clase main?

Comment: Voy a tratar de explicarlo en una respuesta, porque un comentario no alcanza para explicar algunos conceptos fundamentales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Dos conceptos fundamentales antes de arrancar

Cuando trabajas en POO (Programación Orientada a Objetos) tienes que dominar algunos conceptos fundamentales, si no, pronto estarás totalmente desorientado en un código spaghetti.

#### 1. *El modelo de datos*

Algunas clases son entidades que representan realidades concretas de la vida misma (esta es una gran ventaja porque ayuda a pensar la programación desde lo concreto del día a día). Así hablamos de una clase `Persona`, una clase `Banco`, una clase `Vehiculo`, una clase `Cuenta` ...

Las clases representan el **modelo de datos** de la aplicación y en ella debes poner todas las propiedades (campos) y operaciones (métodos) de esa entidad.

Por ejemplo, ¿qué propiedades tendría una cuenta? Por poner algunas: un nombre de `cliente`, un `tipo` de cuenta, un `agente` de cuenta (empleado del banco), etc. El modelo de datos es algo que debe estar bien montado, de lo contrario no podrás aprovechar todas las bondades de la POO. Por ejemplo, el miembro `cliente` de la clase `Cuenta` debería ser un objeto de la clase `Cliente` que extendería quizá de la clase `Persona`<sup>1</sup> ... Para no liarnos demasiado, en el ejemplo de código declararamos cada propiedad de la clase `Cuenta` como de un tipo primitivo.

Pasemos ahora a los métodos... Por ejemplo, ¿qué operaciones se hacen en una entidad `Cuenta`? Por decir sólo algunas: retirar dinero, ingresar dinero, pedir un saldo de la cuenta... Pues bien, tu clase `Cuenta` debe tener **métodos** que hagan esas operaciones. Significa que `Cuentas` tendrá los métodos `retirarDinero()`, `ingresarDinero()`, `pedirSaldo()`<sup>2</sup>.

Dentro de esos métodos habría que poner **la lógica** que conlleva cada operación. Tomemos el caso de `retirarDinero()`. Si piensas en la vida real, ya tienes clara la lógica que ese método debería reflejar:
    - a. tendría que recibir en parámetro la cantidad que se quiere retirar, 
    - b. verificar si hay saldo suficiente para entregar ese dinero, 
    - c. si lo hay, devolver la cantidad que se solicitó
    - d. deducir del saldo actual esa cantidad

> Hago un inciso aquí porque este es el *quid* de tu pregunta:
>
> ***<sup>¿cómo puedo restar ese valor de retiro al monto inicial estabecido en monto y poder guardarlo?</sup>***
>
> Eso tiene que estar reflejado en tu clase `Cuenta`. De modo que cuando retires dinero, con el simple hecho de hacer algo así, todo se
>   realice de forma transparente:
>
> ```
>       mCuenta=new Cuenta(...);
>       mCuenta.retirarDinero(50);
>       System.out.println(mCuenta.getSaldo()); //Imprimiría el nuevo saldo
> ```

En definitiva, una clase del **modelo de datos** (como `Cliente` u otras) debería ser pensada **como un molde** que sirve para fabricar todos los clientes que hagan falta, **en el contexto** donde haga falta. Es importante tener claro que cuando modelas una clase, debes pensar muy seriamente cuáles son las cosas propias de ella, para no dotarla de propiedades que rompan el modelo. Suponte una clase `Avion` a la que le pones dentro una propiedad del tipo `Camion`, o a la que le pones una propiedad del tipo `Scanner` o en la que usas un `Scanner` dentro de alguno de sus métodos.

Algo que parece tonto, pero que ayuda mucho a entender las clases, es la *convención* de nombre. Salvo contadas excepciones, hay que darles nombre en singular, no en plural: `Persona`, `Cliente`, `Usuario`, `Gerente`. La clase representa una entidad, un cliente, no un grupo de clientes...

---

### 2. *El contexto*

Hay otras clases que son parte del **contexto** de la aplicación. Tal es el caso de tu clase principal (donde se encuentra el método `main`). En el contexto, según lo que necesitemos, crearemos instancias de las clases del modelo (vistas en el punto 1), llenaremos esas instancias, operaremos con ellas **a través de sus métodos**, etc.

Me he alargado un poco, debido a no haber tenido tiempo para ser más breve. Simplemente, si tienes claro el modelo de datos y el contexto, ya estarás bien encaminado en la POO. En cambio, si empiezas mal con esos conceptos, vas a pasar mucho trabajo programando.

La no comprensión de esos conceptos se va claramente en esta parte de tu código, por poner sólo un ejemplo:

```
    public static Cuentas nuevaCuenta(int nC, String usuario, String contra, String nombre, int monto, int tipo){
        Cuentas cuenta = new Cuentas();
        cuenta.setnC(nC);
        cuenta.setUsuario(usuario);
        cuenta.setContra(contra);
        cuenta.setNombre(nombre);
        cuenta.setMonto(monto);
        return cuenta;
    }
```

¿Qué sentido tiene ese método en el contexto? ¡Eso debería hacerlo **el constructor de la clase `Cliente`!**

Es decir, puedes prescindir totalmente de ese método y cambiar esto:

```
cuentas[cnt] = nuevaCuenta(nC, usuario, contra, nombre, monto, tipo);
```

Por esto:

```
cuentas[cnt] = new Cuenta(nC, usuario, contra, nombre, monto, tipo);
```

El error (de concepto) aquí es que la lógica del **constructor** de la clase `Cuenta` la estás aplicando en el contexto, invocando a `nuevaCuenta()` y luego invocando a los *setter*  de la clase. Todo eso es redundante cuando puedes dotar a la clase de un constructor que reciba esos parámetros y cree instancias de la clase con esos datos, como veremos en la respuesta.

Además, a nivel de rendimiento, el objeto es modificado 5 veces (aplicando 5 setter sobre él), cuando se puede haber creado con una sola llamada a `new()`.

Además, siempre a nivel de rendimiento, estás traficando con 5 variables extras que pasas al método `nuevaCuenta`.

Todo eso, en contexto de mucho uso va a tener impacto a nivel de rendimiento, aunque éste sea insignificante, tu código no está optimizado.

---

## Resolviendo el problema

Simplemente te mostraré una clase `Cliente` simplificada (o sea, pondré los métodos a utilizar para este caso). Y en el `main` pondré ejemplos puestos a mano dado que el fiddle no permite `Scanner`.

Lo importante es que desde el contexto puedes informar a la clase y operar sobre ella. Luego eso lo adaptas con el `Scanner` en tu clase principal.

### Código

#### Clase principal, que sería donde tienes el main

Aquí la clase se llama `Rextester` porque así lo exige el fiddle. Esta es, por llamarla de alguna manera, una clase contextual, donde aplicas cierta lógica para trabajar con clases del modelo de datos, como lo es `Cuenta`.

En esta clase tú vas a hacer uso de las bondades de `Cuenta`, como es el hecho intentar retiros de dinero sin preocuparte de nada más que pasarle la cantidad. La lógica implementada en la clase se encargará de hacer las verificaciones de lugar y eso tiene una utilidad enorme porque puedes trabajar con millones de cuentas sin preocuparte de nada.

```
class Rextester
{
    public static ArrayList<Cuenta> mCuentas = new ArrayList<Cuenta>();

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        /*
            Puede que el método crearCuenta() de tu código
            con un Scanner dentro, sea otro error de concepto
            el Scanner podría estar aquí, y desde aquí llenar la lista de cuenta
            Si no, cada vez que llames a crearCuenta() estarías abriendo un Scanner
            y eso afecta el rendimiento del código
        */

        /*
            Imaginemos que aquí está el Scanner, lo hacemos a mano por brevedad
        */
        String mUsuario="Usuario1"; //nextLine()...
        String mContra="contra1";   //nextLine()...
        String mNombre="Nombre1";  //nextLine()...
        int mMonto=100;             //nextLine()...
        int mTipo=1;                //nextLine()...

        /*
            Aquí en vez de llamar al extinto método nuevaCuenta()
            usamos el constructor de la clase
            Crearemos primero un objeto para hacer pruebas sobre el método retirarDinero
        */
        Cuenta mCuentaTest=new Cuenta(cnt,mUsuario,mContra,mNombre,mMonto,mTipo);

        /*
            Intentamos:
             1. retirar dinero inferior al monto
             2. retirer dinero superior al monto
             Dado que el método devuelve una cadena, podemos hacer
             una prueba directa usando System.out...
         */
         System.out.println(mCuentaTest.retirarDinero(10)); //Ok. Has retirado 10  y tu monto actual es 90
         System.out.println(mCuentaTest.retirarDinero(91)); //No puedes retirar 91 porque tienes un monto de 90

        /*
            Usaremos un método para llenar al array de Cuentas 
            y dentro de ese método un bucle
        */
        crearCuenta();

        /*
            Estas son llamadas a métodos aplicables en cualquier contexto.
            A modo de prueba, nuestra clase Main va a tener:
              1. un método para leer las cuentas que haya en la lista creada al llamar a crearCuentas()
              2. un método que va a intentar retirar dinero aleatorio en las cuentas
            Lo importante es entender que una cosa es el contexto
            y otra muy distinta el modelo de datos
            una de las claves de la POO es saber combinar ambas cosas de modo adecuado
        */
        leerCuentas();
        retirarDineroAleatorio();
    }

    public static void crearCuenta()
    {
        /*
            Aquí usarías tu Scanner
            dado que este fiddle no permite Scanner, usaré un bucle
        */

        String mUsuario="";
        String mContra="";
        String mNombre="";
        int mMonto=0;
        int mTipo=1;
        Random rand = new Random(); //Esto es para generar montos aleatorios para la prueba

        /*
            Cuando se trabaja con objetos es mucho más comodo usar ArrayList
            para coleccionar dichos objetos, por eso hemos declarado mCuentas
            en ese caso se usa add para agregar los objetos
            y dentro podemos invocar al constructor de la clase
            Eso revela la redundancia del extinto método nuevaCuenta
            Aquí imaginamos que en un contexto de Scanner o cualquier otro
            recoges varios valores, esos valores se pueden ir agregando a la lista
        */        

         for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
         {
             mUsuario="Usuario"+i;
             mContra="Contra"+i;
             mNombre="Nombre"+i;
             mMonto = rand.nextInt(1000);
             mTipo=1;
             mCuentas.add(new Cuenta(i,mUsuario,mContra,mNombre,mMonto,mTipo));
         }        
    }

    public static void leerCuentas()
    {
        for(Cuenta cuenta : mCuentas)
        {
            System.out.println(cuenta.toString());
        }
    }
    /*Esto es sólo una prueba de contexto*/
    public static void retirarDineroAleatorio()
    {
        Random rand = new Random(); //Esto es para generar montos aleatorios para la prueba
        for(Cuenta cuenta : mCuentas)
        {
            /*
                La salida de este código será siempre distinta
                porque usa valores aleatorios
                Esto es sólo a modo de prueba
            */
            System.out.println(cuenta.retirarDinero(rand.nextInt(1000)));
        }
    }    


}
```

---

#### Clase `Cuenta`

Esta clase, como venimos diciendo, forma parte del modelo de datos y te servirá para trabajar con todas las cuentas. Sea desde el `main` o desde un millón de sitios en tu aplicación, donde necesites trabajar con algún cliente, vas a usar esta misma clase, teniendo encapsulada en ella toda la lógica relativa a clientes: métodos, propiedades, etc.

Hablamos desde cosas simples hasta cosas complejas. Imagina que se necesite un historial de balances de cada cliente. Esa lógica, que sería complicada desde otros sitios, pensando que la aplicarás aquí, es un alivio.

Este modelo es muy básico, por razones de brevedad... Faltan métodos y propiedades.

```
class Cuenta
{
    private int nC;
    private String usuario;
    private String contra;
    private String nombre;
    private int monto;     //El tipo de dato para este campo debería ser Decimal o BigDecimal
    private int tipo;


    /*
        Un constructor que podrás invocar
        para crear instancias de Cuenta con datos dentro
        NÓTESE: que una clase puede tener varios constructores
    */
    public Cuenta(int nC, String usuario, String contra, String nombre, int monto, int tipo) {
        this.nC=nC;
        this.usuario=usuario;
        this.contra=contra;
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.monto=monto;
        this.tipo=tipo;

    }
    /*
        Omitiré los getter y setter por brevedad
    */

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("No: %d usr: %s name: %s ammount: %d type: %d",nC,usuario,nombre,monto,tipo);
    }

    /*
        Esta es una versión simple del método retirarDinero
        Básicamente verifica:
          - si la cantidad solicitada no es mayor al monto
          - si lo es, actualiza el monto de la cuenta
          - retorna un mensaje adecuado según cada caso
        Otras validaciones y controles podrían convenir aquí
        como verificar si cantidad es numérico, etc.
    */
    public String retirarDinero(int cantidad){
        if (cantidad < monto) {
            monto-=cantidad;
            return String.format("Cuenta nº %d: Has retirado %d  y tu monto actual es %d",nC,cantidad,monto);
        }
        return String.format("Cuenta nº %d: No puedes retirar %d porque tienes un monto de %d",nC,cantidad,monto);
    }
}
```

---

#### Salida de las pruebas

Primeras dos pruebas que hicimos:

```
Cuenta nº 1: Has retirado 10  y tu monto actual es 90
Cuenta nº 1: No puedes retirar 91 porque tienes un monto de 90
```

Cuando creamos varias cuentas en el bucle:

```
No: 1 usr: Usuario1 name: Nombre1 ammount: 804 type: 1
No: 2 usr: Usuario2 name: Nombre2 ammount: 210 type: 1
No: 3 usr: Usuario3 name: Nombre3 ammount: 568 type: 1
No: 4 usr: Usuario4 name: Nombre4 ammount: 995 type: 1
No: 5 usr: Usuario5 name: Nombre5 ammount: 541 type: 1
No: 6 usr: Usuario6 name: Nombre6 ammount: 416 type: 1
No: 7 usr: Usuario7 name: Nombre7 ammount: 292 type: 1
No: 8 usr: Usuario8 name: Nombre8 ammount: 80 type: 1
No: 9 usr: Usuario9 name: Nombre9 ammount: 929 type: 1
```

Cuando hicimos la prueba de retirar dinero aleatorio:

```
Cuenta nº 1: Has retirado 515  y tu monto actual es 289
Cuenta nº 2: Has retirado 113  y tu monto actual es 97
Cuenta nº 3: Has retirado 401  y tu monto actual es 167
Cuenta nº 4: Has retirado 218  y tu monto actual es 777
Cuenta nº 5: Has retirado 163  y tu monto actual es 378
Cuenta nº 6: Has retirado 246  y tu monto actual es 170
Cuenta nº 7: No puedes retirar 834 porque tienes un monto de 292
Cuenta nº 8: No puedes retirar 595 porque tienes un monto de 80
Cuenta nº 9: Has retirado 79  y tu monto actual es 850
```

---

#### Demo

Aquí tienes una demostración en línea para poder hacer otras pruebas que te ayuden a entender los conceptos sobre los que tengas dudas.

<kbd>[**`DEMOSTRACIÓN`**](https://rextester.com/edit/HADS53366)</kbd>

### Notas

1. Ahí entraríamos ya en cuestiones como la *herencia*  que es otro concepto fundamental de la POO, pero no nos metamos por ese camino ahora. Sin embargo es importante no perder de vista que sin un modelo de datos bien diseñado la POO más que una solución se convierte rápido en un problema.
2. Hay que decir que el modelo de datos puede refinarse aún más, por ejemplo haciendo que las operaciones sean manejadas por una clase `Transaccion`, la cual tendría reflejadas todas las operaciones posibles sobre objetos `Cuenta`, sobre objetos parecidos como `Hipoteca`, `Prestamo`, etc. Esto es importante tenerlo presente para entender la importancia fundamental de un modelo de datos bien estructurado.

Comment: He estado viendo el código y, ya voy entendiendo cómo estructurarlo; sin embargo, me surgieron algunas dudas, por ejemplo ¿Cómo puedo almacenar los datos en el ArrayList cuando son dinámicos y no estáticos?... y anteriormente podía validar usuario y contraseña según las posiciones en el array pero ¿Cómo podría hacerlos con un ArrayList?

Comment: @OscarAnibal si revisas el método `crearCuenta()` podrás ver que los elementos se crean de forma dinámica. Allí hay un bucle `for` que crea los elementos. Se crea cada miembro de la clase de forma dinámica y luego se agrega a la lista con `add` de este modo: **`mCuentas.add(new Cuenta(i,mUsuario,mContra,mNombre,mMonto,mTipo));`** En cuanto a acceder a un elemento en una posición determinada, también puedes hacerlo con suma facilidad en un `ArrayList`.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Checaré cómo ir trabajando con ArrayList.